# CodeIgniter - Ion Auth - TCPDF lose session when print a pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, tcpdf, ion-auth

In my project I have strange things happening when I create a pdf through TCPDF. 
It prints data (if data are not including something about the user actually logged in) and then I always lost the session and I have to login again.

Other thing that I don't understand...if I echo the session in the same controller where I create the pdf:
    print_r($this->session->userdata);
it doesn't work (obviously) but neither lost the session and it don't log out.

I'm using Ion Auth as authentication library.

My test.php controller is called from a view :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" style="margin:1%;float:right" href='http://teddybe.it/anita/index.php/test/stampa_assistiti/'> Stampa </a></td>
```

I just changed one from tcpdf examples:

```
class Test extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("Pdf");
    $this->load->model('assistiti_m');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function stampa_assistiti() {
// create new PDF document
...
...
...

$data['assistiti'] = $this->assistiti_m->assistiti();

foreach($data as $post){
    foreach ($post as $p) {
        $nome = $p->nome;
        $cognome =  $p->cognome;
        $residenza =  $p->residenza;
        $tribunale = $p->tribunale;
        $giudice =  $p->giudice;

        $tbl .= '<tr><td style="border:1px solid #D2D2D2;text-align:center;color:#333;font-size:14px;height:25px">'.$nome.'</td>'; 
        $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #D2D2D2;text-align:center;color:#333;font-size:14px">'.$cognome.'</td>';
        $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #D2D2D2;text-align:center;color:#333;font-size:14px">'.$residenza.'</td>';
        $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #D2D2D2;text-align:center;color:#333;font-size:14px">'.$tribunale.'</td>';
        $tbl .= '<td style="border:1px solid #D2D2D2;text-align:center;color:#333;font-size:14px">'.$giudice.'</td></tr>';
    }
;}

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header.$tbl.$tbl_footer , true, false, false, false, '');   
// ---------------------------------------------------------    

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('lista_assistiti.pdf', 'I');    
}
```

And here is my model:

```
function assistiti()
{
    $user =  $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $userId = $user->id;
    $query = $this->db->get_where('assistiti', array('assistito_da' => $userId));
    return $query->result();
}
```

The code is very linear and basic so I think it's here the problem, but I really can't figure out if it's about Codeigniter or Ion Auth and what I can do to solve it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!